# How to make global changes to Access forms?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've inherited a database which has a tabbed form, which in turn has tabbed subforms. Many of the subforms have a label that has to be corrected.  If this were a Word document or Excel workbook, I'd use Find-and-Replace-All. You can't do that across controls on forms, can you?

Is there a way to do so using VBA? I think it would look something like:

```
 Set aForm = Me
 For each aPage in aForm.Pages
     For each aControl in aPage.Controls
          if aControl.type = "Label" then
               if aControl.Value = "OldText" then aControl.Value = "NewText"
          end if
     Next aControl
 Next aPage
```

EDIT  -------------

I tried this code:

```
 For Each aForm In Application.CurrentProject.AllForms  
     For Each aPage In aForm.Pages  '<---- Error here
         For Each aControl In aPage.Controls
              If aControl.Type = "Label" Then
                   If aControl.Value = "OldText" Then aControl.Value = "NewText"
              End If
         Next aControl
     Next aPage
 Next aForm
```

But I get an error where I put that arrow. It says "Object doesn't support this property or method", which means it doesn't like "aForm.Pages". What's the right way to cycle through tabbed pages?

Comment: Seems you're only missing something like `For Each aForm In Application.CurrentProject.AllForms` to wrap this logic, and then move that to a `Public Sub` in a separate standard module (.bas), and run it from the immediate pane.

Comment: Related: [Microsoft Access - Loop through all forms and controls on each form](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34901810/1188513)

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I've started a question on SO, fully describe the problem, realize the *answer* to the problem, then cancel the question. I guess this was almost one of those times!

Comment: You don't need to cycle through the Tab pages. A form will have all controls in its control collection including the tab and all controls in all tab pages. just do for each aControl in aForm.controls ...